# How to produce .a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

I am sorry for this beginner's question:

I have created a static library, and now I want to produce the .a, but with no luck.

I expect to have a .a in "Products" group after I press Build or Run, but it is not there.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A "static library" normally *is* a `.a` (archive) file. What is it that you have, being a static library but *not* `.a`?

Having no experience with Obj-C, cocoa *or* iPhone development, I can only say that a C/C++ developer would use [`ar`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/binutils/ar.html#ar) to put multiple `.o` files into one `.a` archive.

Comment: O, I am sorry...
It was there all along. My mistake. I was expecting to have LPManager.a, but the file that was created was named according to the group: libLBSDK.a